# Highlight the meaning of the passage with reference to the difficult words

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is an extraction from FATHERHOOD by Bill Cosby. Some of the words and phrases make its understanding really difficult. Dictionary is of no help. Please explain what this passage means:

"I know I don't sound hip talking like this, but no matter how he talks, a father cannot sound hip to his children...He can GIVE HIGH FIVES UNTILL HIS PALMS BLEED; he can say "CHILLY DOWN" so much that he sounds like a short order cook, but a father will still be a man who lost all his hipness at twenty-three when he started paying rent."

Comment: Interpretation requests (criticism, discussion, analysis, and divining the author’s intent) are out of scope and may be removed. This applies to all English texts and utterances, song lyrics, poetry, and legal documents. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” ask that question instead. Also check out the *[Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com/)*.

Answer (score 3):

These are slang terms.  See [*Green's Dictionary of Slang*](https://greensdictofslang.com):

**high five** n.1  [the number of fingers on a hand and the height of the gesture; cf. low five n.]
[1980s+] a greeting or celebratory gesture that takes the form of raising the arm and ritualistically slapping palms with someone.

[If you keep on giving someone a high five, you will end up with a bleeding, or at least sore, hand.]

**chilly down** (v.) [1980s+] (US) to pass the time of day, to ‘hang out’.

Comment: Good stuff. Worth adding something about the 'until his palms bleed' part? Just for completeness?

Comment: *Spagirl --Done!

Comment: "Chilly down" was new to me -- I'd only come across before it in the form "Chill out".  Perhaps it's more locally American than the version I'm familiar with.

Comment: @RobinHamilton  What then SAYING "CHILLY DOWN" mean?

Comment: It's difficult to say, given the lack of context in the Cosby original -- possibly, "Shall we hang out together?" I'd paraphrase as, "Shall we talk?" or "Shall we go for a coffee?"  Maybe, as it stands, it's **meant** to indicate the speaker's ineptitude when it comes to 80s teenage slang.

Comment: @MShehzad - It probably means, "Stay cool, man."

Comment: Cosby is saying a father never appears hip to his own children.

Comment: @aparente001  That would fit with "Chill (out)", but "Chilly down" seems to have a different meaning.  But as all we have in the Cosby text is the bare phrase with no context, it's impossible work out the exact meaning intended.

Comment: @RobinHamilton - I found something.  http://www.wordsandphrasesfromthepast.com/dictionary-c---pg-3.html  "to take it easy, to relax, to calm down."

Comment: This is weird -- that gives the date of 1986 and ... turns out that the **_only_** instance of "chilly down" which exists is this very one from Bill Cosby! _GDoS_ cites it from _The Historical  Dictionary of American Slang_, and there, Jon Lighter implies that it's a version of, or mistake for, "chill out". So it's strictly a one-off thing, a total mistake, deliberate or otherwise, on Cosby's part. So much trouble over nothing ... Bleh!!!

Answer (score -1):

Bill Cosby means to say that father tries to be up-to-date with his children,giving high fives until his palms bleed..then he calms them down by fulfilling their desires like a cook who prepares orders quickly. Despite all the frankness, the fact is that he is still a father and generation gap still persists.And secondly he has lost hipness at the age of 23 when he started shouldering the responsibilities of household and family.He has become mature and there must be a difference in the likes and dislikes between father and the son.

Answer (score -2):

i suppose that i may not be looking hip if i talk like that but in whatever manner a father can never be hip to his own children. A father can respond and respond to prove to be hip untill that he cant do it any further because if you keep on giving high fives, your palm is liable to bleed. A father may try to let the children feel calm and to act like a ready-at-hand provider.